# Object of type QuerySet is not JSON serializable Django JSON

Tags: python, json, django, django-models, jsonresponse

Everything works **until I try to Return JsonResponse** 
I'm looping through the list, which contains usernames then passing those usernames to the models which return basic user information and storing those values in a variable which I later added to the list.

```
def jsonresponse(request, username):

   Current_User = User.objects.get(username=username)
   #List of who this user follows
   followingList = Follower.objects.filter(follower=int(Current_User.id))

   UsersInfo = []
   for user in followingList:
       singleUser = User.objects.filter(username=user.following).values( 'username','bio', 'profile_image')
       UsersInfo.append(singleUser)


   results = User.objects.filter(username=Current_User).values( 'username','bio', 'profile_image') **This Works**

   return JsonResponse({'results':list(results), 'UsersInfo':list(UsersInfo)})
```

This works **'results':list(results)**,
This doesn't **'UsersInfo':list(UsersInfo)**

**print(results) gives me this:**

```py
<QuerySet [{'username': 'John', 'bio': 'Hello, im new!', 'profile_image': 'images/ape_xhRtC2R.jpg'}]>
```

**print(UsersInfo) gives me this:**

```py
[<QuerySet [{'username': 'Tristan', 'bio': 'Hello, im new!', 'profile_image': 'images/1-scary-tiger-head-robbybubble.jpg'}]>, <QuerySet [{'username': 'William', 'bio': 'Hello, im new!', 'profile_image': 'images/ape_PvPNwCP.jpg'}]>]
```

Any help would really be appriciated

Comment: `UsersInfo += singleUser`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can't believe that's what I was missing, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
singleUser = User.objects.filter(username=user.following).values( 'username','bio', 'profile_image')
```

to

```
singleUser = User.objects.get(username=user.following).values( 'username','bio', 'profile_image')
```

You just get user object insted of QuerySet each time.